# Use variable in RewriteCond match

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running a site in 2 environments: production and development.

Each server has a `vhosts.conf` file, which sets environment variables. One of these variables is the correct subdomain to use.

**vhosts.conf** (development server)

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=DEV_OR_WWW:dev]
```

**vhosts.conf** (production server)

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=DEV_OR_WWW:www]
```

I also have a `.htaccess` file, which is identical on both servers. I am trying to rewrite old domain urls into new ones, while preserving the subdomain, like this:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "%{ENV:DEV_OR_WWW}\.olddomain\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "^/(.*)"  "http://%{ENV:DEV_OR_WWW}.newdomain.com/$1" [L,R=301]
```

---

But the RewriteCond above does not work. `%{ENV:DEV_OR_WWW}` is not matching `www` or `dev`, and the rule is not applied. How can I use a variable to match the HTTP_HOST against?

If you need more details, or if my question is unclear, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:DEV_OR_WWW} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %1.olddomain.com ^(www|dev)\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://%1.newdomain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @starkeen. Nice trick, using `(www|dev)`. I'm trying it out, I'll get back to you.

Comment: remove the leading slash from the rewriterule's pattern if you are testing this on .htaccess context.

Comment: You are right about the slash. However, it's not working (Error: Too many redirects). I'm guessing that is because that rule is applied on every request. It should be applied only if the `%{HTTP_HOST}` is on the old domain. Itried this on the second line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|dev)\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]` but it did not work either :(